# No funciona Last-child en css

Tags: html, css

Estoy tratando de hacer un `background` con `last-child` y no entiendo muy bien por que no aplica el estilo que deseo. Quiero que el ultimo `div` que contenga la clase hijo tenga el `background`, como puedo hacerlo?. ALGO ESTA MAL.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html> 
 <html> 
 <head>   
    <style type="text/css">
        
        .hijo {
            display: block;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            border:1px solid red;
        }


        .hijo:last-child {
            background: #ff0000;
        }

        .hermano {
            display: block;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            border: 1px solid green; 
        }

    </style>
</head> 
<body>   
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 100vh; border: 1px solid #000;">
        <div class="hijo">
            <p>ESTO ES UN TEST</p>
        </div>
        <div class="hijo">
            <p>ESTO ES UN TEST</p>
        </div>
        <div class="hijo">
            <p>ESTO ES UN TEST</p>
        </div>
        <div class="hijo">
            <p>ESTO ES UN TEST</p>
        </div>
        <div class="hijo">
            <p>ESTO ES UN TEST</p>
        </div>
        <div class="hermano"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como ya te han dicho, el estilo solo aplica al elemento .hijo que sea último elemento de su padre, por lo que si quieres que quede como creo que estoy entendiendo, simplemente deberías añadir un 'div' sin estilos entre los elementos de la clase hijo.

```
    <div>
        <div class="hijo">
            <p>ESTO ES UN TEST</p>
        </div>
        <div class="hijo">
            <p>ESTO ES UN TEST</p>
        </div>
        <div class="hijo">
            <p>ESTO ES UN TEST</p>
        </div>
        <div class="hijo">
            <p>ESTO ES UN TEST</p>
        </div>
        <div class="hijo">
            <p>ESTO ES UN TEST</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hermano"></div>
```

Comment: A esto quería llegar muchas gracias amigo :) esta es la respuesta

Answer (score 3):

Esto ocurre porque estas aplicando `css` a los elementos con clase `.hijo` que sean `last-child`.

Esta comprobacion se hace dentro de un contenedor padre que en este caso es un DIV

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100vh; border: 1px solid #000;">
        <div class="hijo">
            <p>ESTO ES UN TEST</p>
        </div>
        <div class="hijo">
            <p>ESTO ES UN TEST</p>
        </div>
        <div class="hijo">
            <p>ESTO ES UN TEST</p>
        </div>
        <div class="hijo">
            <p>ESTO ES UN TEST</p>
        </div>
        <div class="hijo">
            <p>ESTO ES UN TEST</p>
        </div>
        <div class="hermano"></div>
    </div>
```

El elemento que cumple con la característica `last-child` en tu caso es

```
<div class="hermano"></div>
```

En resumen, no existe ningun `div` con clase `hijo` que sea el último hijo `last-child` de un contenedor

Si eliminas el último `div` con clase `hermano` verás que ahora si existe un elemento con clase `hijo` que sea `last-child` y se aplicará el `css` correctamente

**EDITO:**

Si lo que pretendes es siempre mantener esa estructura y conservar el elemento `div` con clase `hermano`, solo tienes que crear una regla para los elementos con clase `hijo` que sean el **penúltimo elemento**.

```
.hijo:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
                background: #ff0000;
            }
```

Comment: Ok, listo pero como puedo hacer algo parecido a last-child para aplicar estilos a ese ultimo div con clase .hijo

Answer (score 2):

Cuando das esta instrucción:

```
.hijo:last-child {
     background: #ff0000;
 }
```

Estás diciendo:

**"Al elemento `.hijo` que es el último hijo de su elemento padre, le aplico este estilo..."**.

El problema en tu código HTML, es que el último hijo del elemento padre, en este caso, el elemento `div`, no es el último elemento `.hijo`, sino que el elemento `.hermano`.

¿La solución? Simplemente remueve el elemento `.hermano` del código HTML.

```css
.hijo {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.hijo:last-child {
  background: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100vh; border: 1px solid #000;">
  <div class="hijo">
    <p>ESTO ES UN TEST</p>
  </div>
  <div class="hijo">
    <p>ESTO ES UN TEST</p>
  </div>
  <div class="hijo">
    <p>ESTO ES UN TEST</p>
  </div>
  <div class="hijo">
    <p>ESTO ES UN TEST</p>
  </div>
  <div class="hijo">
    <p>ESTO ES UN TEST</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: pero necesito que el elemento .hermano siempre este, no puedo eliminarlo.

Answer (score 1):

Para lograr eso necesitas cambiar de selector, no puedes usar `last-child` por que no existe un elemento con clase hijo que sea el último hijo del contenedor padre, debes usar `:nth-child(n)` y seleccionar el elemento requerido por medio de su índice que en este caso seria el 5.

Ejemplo:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html> 
 <html> 
 <head>   
    <style type="text/css">
        
        .hijo {
            display: block;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            border:1px solid red;
        }


        .hijo:nth-child(5) {
            background: #ff0000;
        }

        .hermano {
            display: block;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            border: 1px solid green; 
        }

    </style>
</head> 
<body>   
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 100vh; border: 1px solid #000;">
        <div class="hijo">
            <p>ESTO ES UN TEST</p>
        </div>
        <div class="hijo">
            <p>ESTO ES UN TEST</p>
        </div>
        <div class="hijo">
            <p>ESTO ES UN TEST</p>
        </div>
        <div class="hijo">
            <p>ESTO ES UN TEST</p>
        </div>
        <div class="hijo">
            <p>ESTO ES UN TEST</p>
        </div>
        <div class="hermano"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Exactamente es lo que quiero algo asi, pero entonces quiero que no sea mediante indicie sino que sea dinamico, es decir, necesito crear ese estilo independientemente si son 3 div con la clase .hijo o si son 5 div con la clase .hijo, asi que no puedo crearlo con el indice. TIENE QUE SER DINAMICO